# Iterating and mapping List of list

Tags: grails

I have a list of list like this

```
[[emplid:01,emplname:alan],[emplid:02,emplname:john],[emplid:03,emplname:ali]]
```

i need the output as

```
[emplid:01,emplid:02,emplid03]
```

can anyone suggest the looping in java or gorrvy

Answer (score 0):

1st off, your collection is a list of `maps`, not lists. Second, your output is impossible, if you want to get a `map`, as the later doesn't support doublets as keys

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get the output you requested, but you can get a list of `emplid`'s:

```
[
    [emplid:01,emplname:'alan'],
    [emplid:02,emplname:'john'],
    [emplid:03,emplname:'ali']
].collect {
    it.emplid
}
```

The output of the above is: `[1, 2, 3]`

For an output like `[emplid1, emplid2, emplid3]` you can do this:

```
[
    [emplid:01,emplname:'alan'],
    [emplid:02,emplname:'john'],
    [emplid:03,emplname:'ali']
].collect {
    "emplid${it.emplid}"
}
```